# What happens when (XL-XC) of a series LCR circuit equals it's resistance during AC flow?

Tags: electric-current

When XL equals XC, **impedance Z becomes equal to R** and the circuit is in **resonance** with the source frequency. But what would be the *effect on impedance, phase power dissipated* when **R=XL-XC** i.e. ***when the difference between inductive reactance and capacitive reactance of an AC circuit equals to its resistance?***

Comment: A schematic would be of use. You're asking about a network of four components (source, L, C, R) but haven't specified the topology.

Comment: Also, this is a homework-like problem (even if it isn't homework). Be specific about what you need help with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are talking about a series LCR circuit since for parallel circuits we plot $1/X_L$ and $1/X_C$ on our phasor diagram instead of $X_L$ and $X_C$.

In that case there is nothing special about having $|X_L-X_C| = R$. It just means the phase angle is 45° since on the phasor diagram the vertical and horizontal vectors have the same length. As far as I know there is nothing special about a phase angle of 45°.

The phasor diagram looks like this. It is not very exciting!

[image: Phasor diagram]